# Converting int to long C++

Tags: c++

This fuction convert Decimal number to Binary (I've founded it on Internet)

```
  foo(long dec)
  {
     long int rem,i=1,sum=0;
     do
     {
         rem=dec%2;
         sum=sum + (i*rem);
         dec=dec/2;
         i=i*10;
     } while(dec>0);
    return sum;
   }
```

As I found out, when I change type "long" to "int", the function doesn't work for number bigger than 1023. The problem is I have to run this function with integer argument (It has to be foo(int dec)). I have tried to use static_cast but I've failed.
`error: cannot convert ‘long int’ to ‘std::ios_base&(std::ios_base&)’ in assignment|`

Is there any way to bypass that or maybe change this function somehow.
Thank you for you help.

Comment: What line of code throws the `std::ios_base` conversion error? That's generally only relevant for doing console input/output.

Comment: I think you made a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: dec=static_cast<long int>(dec2);

Comment: There's no `dec2` in this code

Comment: Throw that function away.  The base-2 human-readable representation of one hundred is "01100100" (a string), not 1100100.  Actually if you just write `100` in your program, it gets stored in binary already.

Comment: So, you show code that works, and ask a question about different code you don't show, which does not work? See any problem with that? :)

Comment: So you get an error on `dec=static_cast<long int>(dec2);`, but you've decided to show us some other code instead. Please update your question so it includes the actual code that you're feeding to the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you define the type that the function is returning in the function definition, and make sure foo is taking a **long int** as an argument.

```
long int foo(long int) {

    code...

}
```

Comment: Wow I'm really sorry. Just like you said it was a problem with the type of method. Thank You !

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this function doesn't exactly "convert decimal to binary". Instead, it will convert a number such that if you print out the result in base 10, then it looks like the binary representation of the number.

Secondly this function definition is invalid because you did not specify a return type.

Of course, if you change `long` to `int` in the parameter list, and add `int` as return type (and your system has smaller `int`s than `long`s - some don't) then it will not work for as may numbers.

For example, if your system has 32-bit ints then `1111111111` is the largest output that will work, and that comes from input `1023`.

I don't know what you're talking about with the static_cast and ios_base error, you must have done something unrelated to this function.